# Getting Image from URL for UIView [Swift]

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

Alright so I've made some handlers and classes to grab data from a URL, its all returning fine, I've checked the URLs are valid and everything.

Anyways, I'm trying to do an NSData(contentsOfURL) on a stored URL in my class for a UIViewController.  I'm successfully printing out String Variables like name, type, description, but I'm having difficulty displaying an UIImage into a Image View on the ViewController.

Here is my Code, it's run when the View loads:

```
func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let card = detailCard {
            title = card.cardTitle

            //Assign Elements
            detailDescriptionLabel?.text = card.description
            typeLabel?.text = card.cardType
            cardTitleLabel?.text = card.cardTitle
            costLabel?.text = card.cardCost

            print(card.cardImageURL)

            if let url = NSURL(string: card.cardImageURL){
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)// <--- ERROR HERE: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
            }

            //Print Log
            //print(card.logDescription)
        }
    }
```

Like the comment says above, I get the error on the `imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)` line:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Here is the code for cardImageURL:

```
var cardImageURL: String {
    return String(format: "http://testyard.example.net/display/images/cards/main/%@", image)
}
//This is a computed variable when a "Card" class object is created.
```

It returns the correct url in a string:

> http://testyard.example.net/display/images/cards/main/armor-of-testing.jpg

I've used this code elsewhere, and it worked fine, why is it throwing errors here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to show how did you declare card.cardImageURL

Comment: please show the result of `print(card.cardImageURL)`

Comment: Please view my edits, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the data being downloaded is an image? You should probably use this line:

```
if let image = UIImage(data: data)`
```

This should stop the error, though you might need to test that your data actually contains an image.

Comment: so I changed my code to `if let url = NSURL(string: card.cardImageURL){
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                if let image = UIImage(data: data!){
                    imageView.image = image
                }
            }` and its stepping into the "if let image" code and still returning the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Out of interest, if you use let cgImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithURL(url), nil, false, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault) and then add this instead of the if let image: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage!)} - does that work?

Comment: figured it out.  adding a "?" after imageView did the trick.  So:  `imageView?.image = image`

Comment: Does the image actually display now? I thought you would have only needed to add the ? if imageView could be nil.

Comment: Yeah it totally works.  Although im not 100% confident in why :/  Possibly because the URL itself it wrapped in an If statement?